# Counting binary relations

Tags: combinatorics, functions, relations

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets, $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$. How many binary relations are there from $A$ to $B$?

As far I read from various resources, binary relations is nothing but just a typical (total) function. Then, does it mean that such possibilities are equal to $n^m$, or not?

Comment: No, absolutely not: most relations are not functions. A relation from $A$ to $B$ is simply a subset of $A\times B$; how many of those are there?

Comment: There are $2^{mn}$ number of subsets of Cartesian product, but I can not analyze how can we build such binary relations using these Cartesian product subsets

Comment: Yes, that’s right, and each of them is a relation from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please provide on how you will implement creating these binary relations using $2^{mn}$ number of subsets?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean, I’m afraid.

Comment: Is the question done by saying that there are $2^{mn}$ number of subsets? We just used what is exactly "binary relation" and how many subsets we got, but what does the question asks is to find number of possible ways to construct binary relations

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Are they the same thing?

Comment: The question that you’ve written justs asks for the number of binary relations from $A$ to $B$, so it simply wants a number; the point is to find out whether you know that the relations from $A$ to $B$ are just the subsets of $A\times B$ and whether you know how to calculate how many subsets there are.

Comment: I see now. Okay, thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!